# Assign users to another company while delete a company Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, assign

Am working with a affliate management site developed in drupal 7

Actually what I want to do is to assign the company users to another company while we delete a company.
We can assign the users to another company via bulk operation.
But how can we achieve the same while we delete a company.
Can any one help me to solve this issue?
Drupal version :7.X

Now:
When we click on edit , there is a popup come with a delete button in the end of page.
When we click on delete button it will take users to delete confirmation page. once click on the delete button in confirmation page, data get deleted.

Requirement:
We need to show the same bulk operation drop down in the delete confirmation window.
Can anyone please suggest how can we achieve this task.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hook that is responsible for the confirmation step is [node_delete_confirm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_delete_confirm/7) and for deletion [node_delete_confirm_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_delete_confirm_submit/7).

So you have to create a rules action like the one you have but it will run on the "before deleting a node" event. There are some **[useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477757/creating-new-event-in-a-module)** **[issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8477757/1365264)** for this.

Alternatively, there is a module that hooks into the deletion process of nodes: [Predelete](https://drupal.org/project/predelete).

Comment: @SeethaRaman Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).